# extractValue function to extract from HTML?

Tags: html, sql, xml, webloadui

So I was working with webload and was using a function called extractValue, but when I googled it to try and find proper use of it, I learned that it is actually a SQL function for extracting XML values (? is this correct?). Now seeing as that XML and HTML are both markup languages, I figured that maybe it would apply for both HTML and XML? But then I realized that extractValue for XML follows the form extractValue(xmldocument, startpoint, endpoint), while an example for the extractvalue i am using looks like

roughNKEY = extractValue("\"NKEY.DUMMY.MENSYS.1\"", "/", document.wlSource, 1)

which seems to have the form extractValue(startpoint, endpoint, htmldocument(i think it's reading from the html page?), 1)

I have no idea where this usage is from or even what language it's in, but it works for the purpose. Does anyone know where I can find more information on this? Is this just like a function exclusive to webload or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please review the documentation.  You can find it in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\RadView\WebLOAD\help_files

There are three documents that contain information about extractValue:

javascript reference manual
scripting guide
IDE user guide

ExtractValue is also generated by the Correlation engine.

In order to extract a value from the page source, you need to insert:

wlHttp.SaveSource = true

Into the IDE node you want to search.